# Opening file with specific format on Linux systems without iteration

Tags: c, linux, file

I have a directory with many thousands of files, all of which have the general format of `***-***.txt` with the exception of one file with the format `***.txt`, which I am guaranteed to have exactly one of & whose exact name I have no way of knowing.

I would like to know if it is possible to open that singular file without iterating over all of the directory, using only C or Linux functions and without invoking `system()`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answer is no, even if there was a way it would just be iterating over the files underneath

Comment: So, you want to find a file without looking at them? For that, use an index or a symlink under a well-known, constant name.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt That might work, except that I would need to delete/rename the original file to the `***-***.txt` format after a while (I didn't mention that in the question), which is possible to do if the linked file name could be extracted. I don't remember if it can or cannot. However, this certainly gave me a lot of ideas. Thank you.

Comment: so, you put a file with a bad name into a very large directory, and now, you have to rename it according to some patterns,  but, you cannot retrieve it without parsing the whole directory, and you can't do that for some reason. Is that correct ? What other informations do you have on this file ? Size ? Timestamp ? Owner ? ..

Comment: What does “iterating over all of the directory” mean? Do you not want to open the directory and use a loop to read the name of each file in it until you find a file with the matching name? What sort of alternative solution do you hope to find, some system call that you pass a regular expression to and it gives you the name of the matching file in the directory?

Comment: @ValeryS. To be more specific, it's a logging directory where once the most recent log `22.01.01.log` gets of a certain size, it gets renamed to `22.01.01-<currentdate>.log` and waits in the directory until it is archived. I want to be able to open that log without iterating over all of the other logs and comparing their dates to match the one I need. So now that you mentioned it, this means that I also know the upper limit file size of the singular log file I want to open.

Comment: One instance _has to_ iterate over the directory, your program, or the underlying library function, or the system function.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Your description is correct. I am hoping for a way to eliminate the amount of iterations I have to do, as I am constrained by having all the files in that one directory.

Comment: Basically, you want to find the filename that doesn't have `-` in it, using a `glob()`-like function.

Comment: While it's possible to do this with a regular expression, I don't think `glob()` can do it. `bash` extended globbing can match it, but I don't think there's an API for it. So you have to write a loop using `readdir()`.

Comment: @Barmar Correct, provided the `glob()`-like function's performance is not a function of the amount of files.

Comment: That's not possible, unless the filesystem has some kind of index specifically designed to support searches like this. I've never heard of one that would optimize this, and it's hard to imagine a practical filesystem design that would.

Comment: If you want a programmatic solution based on files in the directory as you describe it, you have to use some software that iterates through the directory entries. That is how directories work. If you want some system-administrative solution, then one is to modify the software producing this log file to report its current name somewhere, such as in a file with a fixed given name. Another is to modify the software that renames the log file to put the renamed log files in another directory, so only the current log file is in the directory.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Which is it, `C` or `C++`?

Comment: @Dúthomhas Either is fine.

Comment: @daedsidog: It is generally discouraged to use multiple language tags except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages. C and C++ are different languages, and source code for one generally does not work in the other. Suppose somebody enters a C++ answer. When some future read looks for a C question about finding files and comes to find this question tagged C, they will not find their C answer. You should pick the language you want to work in and delete the other tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted, there is no way to avoid iterating over filenames.
The good news is that it really doesn’t matter. Even with thousands of entries (wut?!) it should not take much time, so if you only need to do it *once*, you are pretty much good to go.

#### C++

```
// Life is easy in C++

#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

fs::path find_magic_file( const fs::path directory )
{
  for (auto & entry : fs::directory_iterator( directory ))
    if (entry.path().stem().string().find( '-' ) == std::string::npos)
      return entry.path();
  return "";
}

int main( int num_directories, char ** directory_names )
{
  for (int n = 1;  n < num_directories;  n += 1)
  {
    auto filepath = find_magic_file( directory_names[n] );
    if (!filepath.empty())
      std::cout << filepath.string() << "\n";
  }
}
```

#### C

```
// C requires you to recur to the OS facilities directly
// This example handles Windows and Linux/POSIX systems

#ifdef _WIN32
  #define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#endif

#include <iso646.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
  #include <windows.h>
  
  char * find_magic_file( const char * directory )
  {
    WIN32_FIND_DATA entry;

    char * dirname = malloc( strlen( directory ) + 5 );
    if (!dirname) return NULL;

    HANDLE h = FindFirstFile( strcat( strcpy( dirname, directory ), "/*.*" ), &entry );
    if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return NULL;
    
    while ((strcmp( entry.cFileName, "."  ) == 0) 
        or (strcmp( entry.cFileName, ".." ) == 0)
        or (strchr( entry.cFileName, '-' )))
      if (!FindNextFile( h, &entry )) 
        break;
      
    FindClose( h );
    free( dirname );
    if (strchr( entry.cFileName, '-' )) return NULL;
    
    char * filepath = calloc( strlen( directory ) + 1 + strlen( entry.cFileName ) + 1, 1 );
    if (filepath) strcat( strcat( strcpy( filepath, directory ), "/" ), entry.cFileName );
    return filepath;
  }
  
#else
  #include <dirent.h>
  #include <sys/types.h>

  char * find_magic_file( const char * directory )
  {
    char * filepath = NULL;
    DIR * dir = opendir( directory );
    if (dir)
    {
      struct dirent * entry;
      while ((entry = readdir( dir )))
      {
        if (!strchr( entry->d_name, '-' )
            and (strcmp( entry->d_name, "."  ) != 0)
            and (strcmp( entry->d_name, ".." ) != 0))
        {
          filepath = malloc( strlen( directory ) + 1 + strlen( entry->d_name ) + 1 );
          if (filepath) strcat( strcat( strcpy( filepath, directory ), "/" ), entry->d_name );
          break;
        }
      }
      closedir( dir );
    }
    return filepath;
  }
#endif

int main( int num_directories, char ** directory_names )
{
  for (int n = 1;  n < num_directories;  n += 1)
  {
    char * filepath = find_magic_file( directory_names[n] );
    if (filepath)
    {
      puts( filepath );
      free( filepath );
    }
  }
}
```

You will notice that the only real difference in `main()` between the two languages is the type of object returned by `find_magic_file()`.

Answer (score 2):

In Linux, you can use POSIX.1 [scandir()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scandir.3.html) function, with a filter function that rejects file names with dashes.

This way, the scanning/iteration is done within the C library, in a manner that is suitable to the operating system at hand, and should not get confused if e.g. files are renamed during the scanning.  In cases where the dashless file is renamed to a dashed one, and another dashed one to a dashless name, exactly during the directory scan, it is possible to not find either name.  (And, if they are done in the reverse order, it is possible to see both names.)

Here is an example program, with full error checking:

```c
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

static int dashless_filter(const struct dirent *ent)
{
    /* Reject file names that begin with a dot '.' ("hidden" files) */
    if (ent->d_name[0] == '.')
        return 0;

    /* Reject file names with dash in them */
    if (strchr(ent->d_name, '-'))
        return 0;

    return 1;
}

char *dashless(const char *dirpath)
{
    struct dirent **list = NULL;
    char           *result = NULL;
    int             num, err;

    /* Return NULL if dirpath is null or empty */
    if (!dirpath || !*dirpath) {
        errno = ENOTDIR;
        return NULL;
    }

    do {
        num = scandir(dirpath, &list, dashless_filter, NULL);
        if (num == -1) {
            err = errno;  /* errno set by scandir() */
            break;
        }

        if (num < 1 || !list || !list[0] || list[0]->d_name[0] == '\0') {
            err = ENOENT;  /* No matching files found */
            break;
        } else
        if (num > 1) {
            err = EMFILE;  /* More than one matching file found. */
            break;
        }

        result = strdup(list[0]->d_name);
        if (!result) {
            err = ENOMEM;
        } else {
            err = 0;
        }
    } while (0);

    /* Free all entries in the list, */
    while (num-->0)
        free(list[num]);
    /* and the list itself. */
    free(list);

    errno = err;
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int  status = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    int  arg;

    if (argc < 2 || !strcmp(argv[1], "-h") || !strcmp(argv[1], "--help")) {
        const char *arg0 = (argc > 0 && argv && argv[0] && argv[0][0]) ? argv[0] : "(this)";
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [ -h | --help ]\n", arg0);
        fprintf(stderr, "       %s DIRECTORY [ DIRECTORY ... ]\n", arg0);
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "This program reports if each specified directory contains\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "a single file without a dash '-' in its name.\n");
        fprintf(stderr, "\n");
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    for (arg = 1; arg < argc; arg++) {
        char *filepath = dashless(argv[arg]);
        if (filepath) {
            printf("%s: %s\n", argv[arg], filepath);
            free(filepath);
        } else {
            if (errno == EMFILE)
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: Multiple dashless files exist.\n", argv[arg]);
            else
                fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", argv[arg], strerror(errno));
            status = EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
    }

    return status;
}
```

Note that it explicitly checks for a single file name.

It would be better if the application or script that generates the files did also create a hard link with a fixed, known name, to the one dashless file, whatever that might be.  That way, one could always use the fixed symlink/hardlink name, and there would not be any race window during which either none or both dashless files would be discovered, if the dashless file is renamed.